# Unable to store NSNumber in core data

Tags: iphone, ios

I am using Core Data in my application.I have an attribute named **PINCode** which has property **Int64**.
Now,in my app I take the PIN code from a text field,convert it into **NSNumber** and try to store as an attribute value for an entity.But I am unable to do so.The exception that it shows on the console is:- 
**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unacceptable type of value for attribute: property = "PINCode"; desired type = NSNumber; given type = NSCFString; value = 121.'**

Here is the code:-
(Conversion to NSNumber):-

```
NSString *str= txtPINCode.text;
NSNumber *num = [[NSNumber alloc]init];
int tempNum = [str intValue];
num = [NSNumber numberWithInt:tempNum];
```

(Storing in core data entity):-

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
NSManagedObject *newContact;
newContact = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"MemberTable" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[newContact setValue:num forKey:@"PINCode"];
```

The app crashes at this point.I am unable to find the reason of crash.I have also tried to check the conversion by the following code:-

```
NSNumber *testNumber = [[NSNumber alloc]init];
id test = num;
BOOL testMe = [test isKindOfClass:(Class)testNumber];
```

Can anybody help me with this??
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried changing the attribute type for `PINCode` to `Int 32`?  You shouldn't need the extra precision of 64 bits on a PIN code field, and the 32-bit iPhone processor might be representing the 64 bit type differently with Core Data.

Comment: You can't just typecast a class instance to a class, like you do in that last line there.  You need to use `[testNumber class]` for that.  In any case, I'm not sure what you're trying to do with the type comparison.

Comment: Also, you're leaking an NSNumber instance on your second line of code above, because you allocate a number, then never release it and overwrite it two lines later.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the first code block is a bit strange. In line 2 you allocate an `NSNumber` then in line 4 you leak that `NSNumber` from line 2 and get a new `NSNumber` object (which gets autoreleased).

So, when you come to second code block, how are those code blocks related? `num` (from code block 1) could point to trash in code block 2.

Try to delete line 2 of code block 1 and in old line 4 write the following:

```
NSNumber *num = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:tempNum];
```

Do not forget to release that later on.